# How to get text value from table in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table of available rooms in a hotel and want to make the text green if it's available. Is it possible to check the innerHTML of an td to see if it says "available"?

```js
var status = document.querySelectorAll("td");
if (status.innerHTML === "available") {
  classList.add("available-green");
}
```

```css
.available-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>booked</td>
    <td>available</td>
    <td>available</td>
    <td>booked</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. `document.querySelectorAll` will return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection as you can get many elements when querying for the `<td>` tag. Thus, as you get multiple elements, you can instead loop through each element in the `NodeList` using `.forEach`.
2. Currently, you are not getting the `.classList` of anything, and so doing `classList.add("available-green");` will not yield results. Instead, when using a `forEach` loop you can instead use the current element (the first parameter of the `.forEach` method) as the element to change the classList of.
3. `status` is a predefined variable which is part of the `window` and it is generally good practice not to use it as it can cause unexpected behavior.
4. Although it is not required, it isn't generally considered good practice to use `.innerHTML` if not retrieving HTML from your element. Instead you can use `.textContent` when just retrieving text.

See working example below:

```js
var tableData = document.querySelectorAll("td"); // start variable names with lowercase letters & class names with upper

tableData.forEach(function(element) {
  if(element.textContent === "available") {
    element.classList.add("available-green");
  }
});
```

```css
.available-green {
  color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>booked</td>
    <td>available</td>
    <td>available</td>
    <td>booked</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property of the Node interface represents the text content of a node and its descendants.

```js
var Status = document.querySelectorAll("td");
Status.forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.textContent === "available") {
    el.classList.add("available-green");
  }
});
```

```css
.available-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>booked</td>
    <td>available</td>
    <td>available</td>
    <td>booked</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i got this error message when i tried to add it to my code: "TypeError: status.forEach is not a function. "

Comment: @AadneHaaland `status` and `Status` different variables. Try `Status` when you set it.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

```js
var statuses = document.querySelectorAll("td");
statuses.forEach(status => {
  if (status.innerHTML === "available") {
   status.classList.add("available-green");
  }
})
```

```css
.available-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>booked</td>
    <td>available</td>
    <td>available</td>
    <td>booked</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll returns a node list which we can work on it as an array, we get an status array to check the value we must loop on it

```js
var Status = document.querySelectorAll("td");
    console.log(Status);
    Status.forEach(element=>{
      if (element.innerHTML === "available"){
      element.classList.add("available-green");

      }
    })
```

```css
.available-green {
      color: green;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>booked</td>
    <td>available</td>
    <td>available</td>
    <td>booked</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```